# PHP __call vs method_exists

Tags: php, overloading

The Project I'm working on contains something like a wrapper for call_user_func(_array) which does some checks before execution.
One of those checks is method_exists (In Case the supplied first argument is an instance of a class and the second is a method name)
The other is_callable.
The function will throw an exception if one of those checks fails.

My Code contains an array with function names (setFoo, setBar, etc.) and the php magic function for overloading (__call) which handles setting, replacing and deletion of certain variables (better certain array elements).

The Problem:
method_exists will return false if the function is not defined.

Do I have any chance to get a true if the __call function does proper handling of the request?

Comment: Great question, I'll play around with this.

Comment: What's needed is another "magic method" __canCall or something...

Comment: is_callable() works with instances of classes. I don't see why you're using method_exists() at all. is_callable() does everything method_exists() does plus it works with __call().

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [`is_callable()`](http://www.php.net/is_callable).

But no, if the `__call()` method only handles some names, then you would need some other way of checking if the call will succeed.

Might I suggest a interface with the method `canCall($function)`, or something? Then check if the class implements the interface. If it doesn't, just use `is_callable()`.

Comment: is_callable() automatically returns true if __call() is defined, making is_callable() undependable (as it doesn't ensure that __call() satisfies the request)

Answer (score 8):

`__call` handles calls to methods that don't exist. `method_exists` is an introspection method that checks the existence of a method.

How can `__call` be determined to handle a method? I think you have to throw an exception manually in `__call` if doesn't handle your request and catch the exception in the code that would otherwise use `method_exists`. [`BadMethodCallException`](http://php.net/BadMethodCallException) exists for this purpose.

Comment: It seems `__call` has no notion of "failing", so it looks like throwing an `NotImplementedException` (or similar) in the __call method would be the way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

method_exists tries two things:

- Searches for the method name in the class's function table.
  Those are the `function foo() {}` type methods.
- Checks if the class (the C code) has a (C code) `get_method()` function and if it has invoke it to let the class implementation decide.

You'd need the latter. But this `get_method()`is not "extended" to the PHP script code, i.e. there is no way to let get_method() call some user defined PHP script code (And what would this PHP code return?).

So the answer to my best knowledge is: No, it's not possible (yet?).

The implementation of `ZEND_FUNCTION(method_exists)` can be found in [`zend/zend_builtin_functions.c`](https://heap.space/xref/PHP-5.4/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#1110) and is I think fairly readable even if you don't know C but PHP.

Answer (score 2):

If you are really sure that _call always has a fall-back, you can do:

```
if (method_exists($this, $method_name) || method_exists($this, '__call')) {
  // Call of the method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to maybe use `method_exists` in your `__call` function and `throw` an `Exception` should this fail and wrap everything in a `try` `catch` block instead of using the `is_callable` function.