# Influence method_exists()

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP __call vs method_exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505696/php-call-vs-method-exists)

I'm using `__call()` instead of methods in a class. Is there any way to influence the result of method_exists() in this class?

Comment: What do you mean by "influence the result"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

__call is just a 'placeholder' for a function call on a class.

Consider this:

```
Class MyClass
{
  private function Bar()
  {
     return 'Bar';
  }

  public function __call($name, $arguments)
  {
    return $this->Bar();
  }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
echo $myClass->Foo( 'Foo' );
```

This code will output 'Bar'
The method 'Foo' does not exists, and by calling $MyClass->Foo('Foo') __call kicks in.

Obviously, method_exists has no way of knowing what __call wil handle.