# Php - data format from rowset

Tags: php

I retrieve from a db the rowset
than depends on the display format
(meter, pie, bar I'm using highchart)
I should manage it.
I ended up with

```
class Model_StatRealtime implements Model_StatsTypeInterface
{

    protected $_rows;
    protected $_translator;
    public function __construct(Model_Rowset_View $rows) 
    {
        $this->_rows = $rows;
        $this->_translator = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate');
    }

    public function getStatType() 
    { 
        return $this->_rows->getStat()->getRealtimeType();
    }

    public function getStatTitle() 
    { 
        return $this->_rows->getStat()->getTitle();
    }

    public function count() 
    { 
        return $this->_rows->count();
    }

    public function getData() 
    { 
        $data = array(); 
        if(method_exists($this,$this->getStatType() )){
           return $this->{$this->getStatType()}();
        }
        return $data;
    }


    protected function meter()
    {
        $data = array();
        if($this->_rows->count() > 0){
            foreach($this->_rows as $row){
                $data[$this->getStatTitle()][] = (int)$row->value;
            }
        }
        else{
            $data[$this->getStatTitle()][] = 0;
        }
        return $data;
    }

    protected function pie()
    {
        $data = array();
        if($this->_rows->count() > 0){
            foreach($this->_rows as $row){
                if($row->value > 0){
                    $data[$this->getStatTitle()][] = array(ucfirst($this->_translator->translate($row['field'])), round($row['value']));
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            $data[$this->getStatTitle()][] = array(0);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    protected function bar()
    {
        $data = array();
        if($this->_rows->count() > 0){
            foreach($this->_rows as $row){
                if($row->value > 0){
                    $data[$this->getStatTitle()][] = array(
                        'name'=>ucfirst($this->_translator->translate($row['field'])),
                        'data'=>array((int)$row['value'])
                        );
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            $data[$this->getStatTitle()][] = array(0);
        }
        return $data;
    }

}
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way.

the use is

$model->getData()

Comment: Does this actually work? Your method_exists function looks incorrect. You could always use overloading too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505696/php-call-vs-method-exists

Comment: I don't see the point [__call handles calls to methods that don't exist. method_exists is an introspection method that checks the existence of a method.] I check if the method exists if not return an array (may be throw an exceptions could be a better way but in my case  is not) [edit] may be  is_callable()  is better than method_exists but __call in this case imho it doesn't the work